# using spread operator to update the state on different levels

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I have a reducer state initialized as follows:

```
state = {
    name: ""
    authenticationObj: {
        userContactInfo: {
            billingAddress: {
                billingCountry: undefined,
                billingAddress1: undefined,
                billingAddress2: undefined,
                billingCity: undefined,
                billingPostalCode: undefined,
                billingPhoneNumber: undefined,
                billingFirstName: undefined,
                billingLastName: undefined,
                billingPersonalEmail: undefined,
                billingSelectedRegion: undefined
            },
        },
        subscriptions: [],
        fullName: "",
        subscriberDefaultPhoneNumber: ""
    }
}
```

Now I need to use spread operator to update the state and here is what I have which is working:

```
case SET_SUBSC_LIST:
    state = { ...state,
        authenticationObj: { ...state.authenticationObj,
            subscriptions: action.payload.subscriptions
        }
    }
```

But what if I want to update the attributes on different levels. For example if I need to update subscriptions and also billingAddress1 which is inside billingAddress at the same time how can I achieve it?

Comment: any reason you're not using `setState` ?

Comment: @samb102 I need to use redux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
state = {
  ...state,
  authenticationObj: {
    ...state.authenticationObj,
    userContactInfo: {
      ...state.authenticationObj.userContactInfo,
      billingAddress: {
        ...state.authenticationObj.userContactInfo.billingAddress,
        billingAddress1: action.payload.billingAddress1   
      }
    },
    subscriptions: action.payload.subscriptions
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [merge](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#merge) method from lodash instead of spread operator so that would be easier to read.

```
case SET_SUBSC_LIST:
    state = _.merge(state, { authenticationObj: {
            subscriptions: action.payload.subscriptions
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to updated both subscriptions and billingAddress1 you can doing the following:

```
    case SET_SUBSC_LIST:
    state = { ...state,
        authenticationObj: { ...state.authenticationObj,
            subscriptions: action.payload.subscriptions,
            userContactInfo:{
                ...state.authenticationObj.userContactInfo,
                billingAddress: {
                    ...state.authenticationObj.userContactInfo.billingAddress,
                    billingAddress1: action.payload.billingAddress1
               }
            }

        }
    }
```

You need to propagate the spread so you maintain the original object and only change the fields that you intent.

Answer (score 1):

Hamed Minaee, you can update diferent fields with the spread Operator, but as samb102 has noted you should use setState:

```
//you can do something like this:
this.setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState,
        authenticationObj: { ...prevState.authenticationObj,
            subscriptions: action.payload.subscriptions,
            userContactInfo: {
                ...prevState.authenticationObj.userContactInfo,
                billingAddress: {
                    ...prevState.authenticationObj.userContactInfo.billingAddress,
                    billingAddress1: "your new state value",
                }
            }
        }
    }))
```

As you can see doing this can be really tedious, so a better way would be to copy the state an directly change the attributes needed:

```
const { authenticationObj } = this.state;

authenticationObj.subscriptions = action.payload.subscriptions;
authenticationObj.userContactInfo.billingAddress.billingAddress1 = "your new state value";

this.setState({ authenticationObj: authenticationObj });
```